# Deploying an ASP.NET web application on IIS 6.0

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deploying an ASP.NET JSON-RPC web service on IIS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/386158/deploying-an-asp-net-json-rpc-web-service-on-iis-7)

I've tried to deploy an ASP.NET web application manually and I'm just getting a directory listing. I've copied the published folder to "C:\intepub\wwwroot", then converted to application. Is there a step I'm missing?

**Edit**: One thing to note is that this application doesn't contains any .aspx pages, it's a web service using Jayrock which provide it's own pages to explore the service interface. When using the application through the VS development web server everything work as expected, I can see the web interface and connect to the service without any problem. But when deployed on IIS, it does nothing at all.

**Edit**: I think it got to do with IIS not able to figure how to start the application handler properly.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck **Directory Browsing** under the *Home Directory* tab for your site in IIS.

Comment: I've tried that and it's giving me a 403.14 error.

Comment: Check your Default Document for the site.  Make sure it exists.

Comment: Well, that's kind of the problem, there's no documents in that application, everything is code and a handler is serving the pages.